# After click the text then how to add data into another component in input text field .setvalue in angular 11

Tags: angular, angular9, angular11

After click the text then how to add data into another component in input text field use setvalue in angular 11. Please see my code given below. Both component with code has been added in this section. My requirement is after click then same text will be added in input field section.

component1.ts

```js
tagname(element){
  let tagDetails = `${element.tagName} ${element.description}`
  console.log("-----------DETAILS-----------", tagDetails);
  this.clickEvent.emit();
  this.router.navigateByUrl("/component2");
}
```

component1.html

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="tagName">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Tag Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><a (click)="tagname(element)">{{element.tagName}}</a></td>
</ng-container>
```

[image]
component2.html

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input type="text" class="input-autocomplete" #myInput placeholder="Search tag" aria-label="Number" matInput
    [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='getPosts($event.option.value)'>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{option}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Subject https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject or ngrx https://ngrx.io/docs to pass data between components. if these component has same parent component, you can pass data with using output without using subject or ngrx.